# Using node.js ForeverAgent

Tags: node.js, connection

To reuse connections when making http.requests I'd like to use the ForeverAgent without having to use the whole request module.

I'm using node v0.8.15

Is that possible? Can someone tell me how?

Answer (score 2):

With the layout/structure of the current version of Mikeal's request module, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
var ForeverAgent = require('request/forever');

var myAgent = new ForeverAgent();
var myRequest = http.request({/* … */, agent:myAgent});
/* … */
```

See the [node.js http documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) for a bit more details on the agent option although it is sparse; I don't see any documentation whatsoever (beyond the source code) for this module's "forever" agent itself.

Answer (score 2):

`ForeverAgent` has recently been split into [its own module](https://github.com/mikeal/forever-agent), so you should just use that.

Comment: i think its not quite there , the 'module' does not even have a package.json ?

Comment: the ForeverAgent came to be from this issue: https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/142

Comment: @mgoetzke The module is there and perfectly useable. You can even do `npm install forever-agent`.